# How to create a shortcut to open new window of nautilus and actiavte this window?

Tags: 13.10, shortcuts

I know how to create a shortcut on Keyboard>Shortcuts. But if I want to create a new window and activate this one, I would like to know.

It shoudl be: nautilus;wmctrl -a nautilus;

but keyboard>shortcut doesn't accept that.

Comment: You could create a Bash script that runs two or more commands. Then set a keyboard shortcut to run your Bash script.

Comment: ....Although I would write the script a bit different these days, it still does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right where you said.  In the Keyboard > Shortcuts menu, simply go to the bottom option - 'Custom Shortcuts' and press the + at the bottom of the window.  Then type a name of your application you want to open, ie, nautilus or files.  In the command field type the command required to activate that program from the terminal, ex: 'nautilus' for nautilus.  Then apply and to set the accelerator (keyboard shortcut) click on 'Disabled' and enter the key combination you want to use to open it.

Comment: But it doesn't activate the window...

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  What keyboard shortcut did you set it to?

Comment: command: nautilus
shortcut: super+e

Comment: Sorry, I meant the actual keyboard shortcut, ie, "ctrl+alt+i", etc.

Comment: Hmm.  What does it do when you press super+e?  Does anything show up?  What if you try different keyboard combinations or different commands?  How much can you get to work?

Comment: if nautilus is already opened, the nautilus icon just shakes, but I keep in my current window

Comment: On 13.10 it doesn't activate window. But in 16.04 it activates. While discovering that I learned how to create an desktop application from .sh that can be very useful to create any shortcut I want.

Comment: Hmm.  Could well be a bug in 13.10 - it wasn't LTS.  My recommendation - upgrade.  Better to be on the LTS or at least the newest version for a production system.

Comment: To open a new Nautilus window from the terminal, use `nautilus -w`. I bound this to the keyboard shortcut `Super + E` and it works fine. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.